# React MaterialUI dynamic font loading

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, material-ui, dynamic-content

We are building a web application where different users see different colors, fonts, border widths, etc depending on the Material UI JSON theme that is pulled from the database when the application loads.

The problem comes with dynamic fonts. **What methods have people tried to dynamically load the font(s) that are needed for the theme?** To be clear, a font that is seen by one user may be different from a font seen by another user.

For example, user one may have the following theme definition:
`"fontFamily": "'Galaxie', sans-serif"`

While user two might have the following theme definition: `"fontFamily": "'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif"`

Typically you would define a CSS file or add a line to the HTML that would load these fonts from the server. However, we would prefer that user one only had to download the `Galaxie` font, while user two only has to download the `Roboto` font.

Current solutions we are thinking of:

- Just make all users load all fonts (not going to work at scale)
- Create a CSS file, to define fonts, that is dynamically populated depending on which user requests it from the server

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://github.com/zachleat/web-font-loading-recipes

Answer (score -3):

You can import custom fonts from here.

https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#raw-css